# How to get current date from epoch ,can anyone help me i m getting 19 jan 1970

Tags: android, json, date

```
String datetime=jsonObject.getString("ReviewDate");
datetime=datetime.replace("Date(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "");
Long ldate=Long.valueOf(datetime);

Date date = new Date(ldate/1000); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));

String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
reviewdate.add(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Voted to close because it is a pure "code only" question. No visible effort to tell us more beside "I am getting wrong result"

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Divide it by 1000 to get the number of seconds.

Comment: not need to use System.currentTimeMillis() you can get desire date and time from epoch by using my code  String datetime=jsonObject.getString("ReviewDate");
datetime=datetime.replace("Date(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "");
Long ldate=Long.valueOf(datetime);
Date date = new Date(ldate); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

Comment: String datetime="1457980200000";
Long ldate=Long.valueOf(datetime);
Date date = new Date(ldate); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);  use this code  u will get result